# Map JSP to servlet

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets

Trying to submit a jsp to servlet. Error during web.xml mapping.

I have

index.jsp

```
<form method="POST" action="Validate">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>validate</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.test.Validate</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>validate</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Validate</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

folder structure

[image]

However, when i try to run on server for `index.jsp`, I get `"server cannot be started"` error

Error goes when servlet mapping is removed from web.xml

Validate.java

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Validate
 */
@WebServlet(description="validation", urlPatterns={"/Validate"})
public class Validate extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Validate() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        System.out.println("validate called");
    }
```

It works when i run as server on `Validate.java`

However, when I run as server on `index.jsp` and click submit. It redirects
to `http://localhost:8080/TestApp/Validate` and nothing on console.

Comment: Can you please share code of `Validate.java`  ?

Comment: You're doing an HTTP POST when you hit submit, but you dont have a doPost method implementation in your servlet.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are using both annotation mapping as well as `web.xml` so you should better remove one of them to make your code work.I believe annotation one is better.

```
@WebServlet(description="validation", urlPatterns={"/Validate"})
```